# ClearContents using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that would delete cells if I open the worksheet every month but sometimes its not open the 1 st of the month. How can I have VBA clear contents to a particular cell range such as C16:G30 once a certain cell that has will input the current date. I have in C1 a formula that will give me todays date (=Today()) So when C1 gives me 3/1/2024 for example or any month that starts with 1 it will automatically delete regardless if I open or dont my worksheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If Day(Date) = 1 Then Sheets("Current Assignments").Range("C17:G30").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: You could save the date of the last run of the macro in a cell. When you open the workbook, check whether the last run was in the previous month.